# Integrating a directive with a WYSIWYG editor

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Context: 
Currently, angular-redactor.js from https://github.com/TylerGarlick/angular-redactor is being used in our application. The goal is to create a new angular directive that can handle any text editor, not just redactor.

So currently we call angular-redactor in the following way:

```
<textarea
      id="title-input"
      ng-model="title"
      ng-disabled="!hasPermission('editPageTitle')"
      height="26px"
      style="resize:none; max-height: 32px"
      redactor="{  buttonsHide: ['link', 'super-script', 'subscript', 'symbol']}">
</textarea>
```

The new implementation of the directive called textEditor.directive.js looks like this:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('MyApp')
        .directive('TextEditor', TextEditor);

    function TextEditor($compile, $window) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            require: '^?ngModel',
            scope: {
                ngModel: '=',
                editorType: '@',
                editorToolbar: '@', // show toolbar or not
                editorConfigPreset: '@', // pass a preset type in order to controlle btn display from css
                editorStyles: '@', // options to pass inline css
                id: '@'
            },
            template: function(scope) {
                var template = '';
                switch (scope.attr('editor-type')) {
                    case 'tinymce':   template =
                        ['<div class="common-redactor hide-toolbar">',
                            '<div class="labeltitle-redactor">',
                            '<textarea ng-model="ngModel" tinymce="" id="{{id}}"></textarea>',
                            '</div>',
                            '</div>'].join('');
                        break;
                    case 'redactor':
                        template = ['<div class="common-redactor hide-toolbar">',
                            '<div class="labeltitle-redactor">',
                            '<textarea ng-model="ngModel" style="{{editorStyles}}" redactor="{{editorConfig}}" id="{{id}}"></textarea>',
                            '</div>',
                            '</div>'].join('');
                        break;
                    default:
                        template =  ['<div class="common-redactor">',
                            '<div class="labeltitle-redactor">',
                            '<textarea  ng-model="ngModel" style="{{editorStyles}}" id="{{id}}" disabled="disabled"></textarea>',
                            '</div>',
                            '</div>'].join('');
                }

                return template;
            },
            link: function (scope, element) {
                    switch (scope.editorType) {
                        case 'redactor':

                            var editorConfig = {
                                default: { buttonsHide: ['orderedlist', 'indent', 'outdent', 'alignment']},
                                toolbar9btn: { minHeight: 100, buttons: ['undo-awesome', 'redo-awesome', 'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'unorderedlist', 'link', 'super-script', 'subscript', 'symbol']},
                                toolbar: { buttonsHide: ['html', 'formatting','deleted','orderedlist', 'indent', 'outdent', 'alignment', 'horizontalrule']}
                            }

                            scope.editorConfig = scope.editorConfigPreset ? editorConfig[scope.editorConfigPreset] : editorConfig.default;


                            if (scope.editorToolbar === 'true') {
                                element.removeClass('hide-toolbar');
                            }

                            // Adds a custom class in order to controll btn display from as current redactor version
                            // does not play nice with angular-redactor
                            element.addClass('toolbar-preset-'+scope.editorConfigPreset);

                            // buggy
                            //angular.element(element).find('textarea').redactor(editorConfig[scope.editorConfigPreset]);

                            break;
                        case 'tinymce':
                            $window.tinyMCE.init({
                                // General options
                                selector : "#title-input6",
                                theme : "advanced",

                                theme_advanced_resizing : false,

                                // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
                                content_css : "css/content.css",

                                // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
                                template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
                                external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
                                external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
                                media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js",

                                // Style formats
                                style_formats : [
                                    {title : 'Bold text', inline : 'b'},
                                    {title : 'Red text', inline : 'span', styles : {color : '#ff0000'}},
                                    {title : 'Red header', block : 'h1', styles : {color : '#ff0000'}},
                                    {title : 'Example 1', inline : 'span', classes : 'example1'},
                                    {title : 'Example 2', inline : 'span', classes : 'example2'},
                                    {title : 'Table styles'},
                                    {title : 'Table row 1', selector : 'tr', classes : 'tablerow1'}
                                ],

                                formats : {
                                    alignleft : {selector : 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes : 'left'},
                                    aligncenter : {selector : 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes : 'center'},
                                    alignright : {selector : 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes : 'right'},
                                    alignfull : {selector : 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes : 'full'},
                                    bold : {inline : 'span', 'classes' : 'bold'},
                                    italic : {inline : 'span', 'classes' : 'italic'},
                                    underline : {inline : 'span', 'classes' : 'underline', exact : true},
                                    strikethrough : {inline : 'del'}
                                },

                                // Replace values for the template plugin
                                template_replace_values : {
                                    username : "Some User",
                                    staffid : "991234"
                                }
                            });

                            break;

                            default:
                        // should be a disabled textarea with ngModel value
                    }
                }
        }
    }
})();
```

CSS is used for some functionality like hiding buttons,

```
.common-redactor textarea[disabled] {
  resize: none;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
  border: none transparent;
  background: transparent; }

.toolbar-preset-default .redactor-toolbar li [rel='undo-awesome'], .toolbar-preset-toolbar .redactor-toolbar li [rel='undo-awesome'], .toolbar-preset-toolbar9btn .redactor-toolbar li [rel='undo-awesome'],
.toolbar-preset-default .redactor-toolbar li [rel='redo-awesome'],
.toolbar-preset-toolbar .redactor-toolbar li [rel='redo-awesome'],
.toolbar-preset-toolbar9btn .redactor-toolbar li [rel='redo-awesome'],
.toolbar-preset-default .redactor-toolbar li [rel='bold'],
.toolbar-preset-toolbar .redactor-toolbar li [rel='bold'],
.toolbar-preset-toolbar9btn .redactor-toolbar li [rel='bold'],
.toolbar-preset-default .redactor-toolbar li [rel='italic'],
.toolbar-preset-toolbar .redactor-toolbar li [rel='italic'],
.toolbar-preset-toolbar9btn .redactor-toolbar li [rel='italic'] {
  display: block; }

.toolbar-preset-default .redactor-toolbar li a, .toolbar-preset-toolbar .redactor-toolbar li a, .toolbar-preset-toolbar9btn .redactor-toolbar li a {
  display: none; }

.toolbar-preset-toolbar .redactor-toolbar li [rel='indent'],
.toolbar-preset-toolbar .redactor-toolbar li [rel='outdent'] {
  display: block; }

.toolbar-preset-toolbar9btn .redactor-toolbar li [rel='underline'],
.toolbar-preset-toolbar9btn .redactor-toolbar li [rel='unorderedlist'],
.toolbar-preset-toolbar9btn .redactor-toolbar li [rel='link'],
.toolbar-preset-toolbar9btn .redactor-toolbar li [rel='super-script'],
.toolbar-preset-toolbar9btn .redactor-toolbar li [rel='subscript'],
.toolbar-preset-toolbar9btn .redactor-toolbar li [rel='symbol'] {
  display: block; }
```

and in HTML is injected like this:

```
<text-editor
        id="title-input4"
        ng-model="title"
        ng-disabled="!hasPermission('editPageTitle')"
        editor-toolbar="true"
        editor-config-preset="toolbar9btn"
        editor-type="redactor">
</text-editor>
```

Where editor-config-preset is used to define a toolbar configuration. The current problem right now is that the toolbar configuration of doesn't seem to follow what we want from the directive. I believe the solution would be to bind ngModel by maybe doing something like element.redactor(config) and recuperating code from angular-redactor and use it inside the textEditor directive but honestly, I have no idea, I simply couldn't get it to work.

For now, I need to get it to work with angular redactor, but the directive should be able to be easily modified to use any text editor.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is quite a good question. Keep up the good work!
(I myself don't know the answer, I found this question from reviewing new users' posts, like yours).